# BeautifulSoup in Python - DIV Contents are not displaying

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to start by saying I reviewed several solutions on this site, but none seem to be working for me.

I am simply trying to access the contents of a div tag from this website: https://play.spotify.com/chart/3S3GshZPn5WzysgDvfTywr, but the contents are not showing.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
SpotifyGlobViralurl='https://play.spotify.com/chart/3S3GshZPn5WzysgDvfTywr'
browser.get(SpotifyGlobViralurl)
page = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
#the div contents exist in an iframe, so now we call the iframe contents of the 3rd iframe on page:
iFrames=[] 
iframexx = soup.find_all('iframe')
response = urllib2.urlopen(iframexx[3].attrs['src'])
iframe_soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
divcontents = iframe_soup.find('div', id='main-container')
```

I am trying to pull the contents of the 'main-container' div but as you will see, it appears empty when stored in the divcontent variable created. However, if you visit the actual URL and inspect the elements, you will find this 'main-container' div statement filled with all of its contents.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

That's because it the container is loaded dynamically. I've noticed you are using `selenium`, you have to continue using it, *switch to the iframe and wait for `main-container` to load*:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

# wait for iframe to become visible
iframe = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//iframe[starts-with(@id, 'browse-app-spotify:app:chart:')]")))
browser.switch_to.frame(iframe)

# wait for header in the container to appear
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#main-container #header")))

container = browser.find_element_by_id("main-container")
```

Comment: this is great, thank you @alexce. can i just ask as a follow-up, now that we have the webdriver element stored in the container variable, how do I actually scrape the contents of the container?

Comment: @user3882316 that depends on what you need from it. If it is just text, then  use `container.text`. You can also locate other elements inside it, see [Locating Elements](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html). Also, to close the topic, see if the answer can be accepted. Thanks.